# Apply function to multiple datasets

Tags: r

**The following function works when the variables (Age, Age2 and Mspline) are in vector format.*

```
Age<-c(2,2.1,2.2,3.4,3.5,4.2,4.7,4.8,5,5.6,NA, 5.9, NA)
Age2<-seq(2,20,0.25)    
Mspline<-rnorm(73)

res <- lapply(1:length(Age), \(x){
  lwr_ind <- max(which(Age2 <= Age[x]))
  upr_ind <- min(which(Age2 >= Age[x]))
  data.frame(Age = Age[x], 
             Mspline = Mspline[lwr_ind] + ((Age[x]-Age2[lwr_ind])/0.25)*(Mspline[lwr_ind] - Mspline[upr_ind]))
})

res <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

*I was wondering how we can modify the function above in order to be used when we have two data sets df1 and df2 and Age, Age2 and Mspline are variables of two data set:**

```
Age<-c(2,2.1,2.2,3.4,3.5,4.2,4.7,4.8,5,5.6,NA, 5.9, NA)
R<-c(2,2.1,2.2,3.4,3.5,4.2,4.7,4.8,5,5.6,NA, 5.9, NA)
df1<-data.frame(Age,R)
# Second data:
Age2<-seq(2,20,0.25)    
Mspline<-rnorm(73)
df2<-data.frame(Age2, Mspline)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
# with vector input data...
set.seed(1234)
Age <- c(2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.4, 3.5, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5, 5.6, NA, 5.9, NA)
Age2 <- seq(2, 20, 0.25)    
Mspline <- rnorm(73)

res <- lapply(1:length(Age), \(x){
  lwr_ind <- max(which(Age2 <= Age[ x ]))
  upr_ind <- min(which(Age2 >= Age[ x ]))
  data.frame(Age = Age[ x ], 
             Mspline = Mspline[ lwr_ind ] + 
               ((Age[ x ] - Age2[ lwr_ind ]) / 0.25) * 
               (Mspline[ lwr_ind ] - Mspline[ upr_ind ]))
})
res1 <- do.call(rbind, res)

# with data.frame input data...
Age <- c(2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.4, 3.5, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5, 5.6, NA, 5.9, NA)
R <- rnorm(13)
df1 <- data.frame(Age, R)
Age2 <- seq(2,20,0.25)
df2 <- data.frame(Age2, Mspline)

res2 <- lapply(1:nrow(df1), \(x){
  age <- df1[ x, 'Age' ]
  age2 <- df2[ , 'Age2' ]
  R <- df1[ x, 'R' ]
  lwr_ind <- max(which(age2 <= age))
  upr_ind <- min(which(age2 >= age))
  data.frame(Age = age, 
             Mspline = df2[ lwr_ind, 'Mspline' ] + 
               ((age - df2[ lwr_ind, 'Age2' ]) / 0.25) * 
               (df2[ lwr_ind, 'Mspline' ] - df2[ upr_ind, 'Mspline' ]),
             R)
})
res2 <- do.call(rbind, res2)

identical(res1, res2[ , 1:2 ])
```

```
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help, could you please modify the code in a way that we could have the final data set (df1) including all variables Age, R and estimated Mspline? (df1 includes R variable as well)

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea regarding the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302480/how-to-modify-an-r-algorithm-loop-function-to-work-for-a-level-of-one-categori